# I should solve a React exercise of a timer and reset it by a button.I have problem with resetting my timer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer

I want to create a timer with a reset button.
I must do this exercise in an initial code that is written by React. This is the initial code.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Timer.css';

export class Timer extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div className="container">
            <div className="timer">
            </div>
            <button>Reset Timer</button>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

I've tried two solution but each of them returned different error. Here is my first solution.(figure 1)
 [figure 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL4fN.png)

and the error is (figure 2)
[figure 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sbx6R.png)

and my second solution is this ... (figure 3)
[figure 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBVjO.png)

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './Timer.css';
const initialState = {
    seconds: 0
  }

export class Timer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = initialState;
      }
       
      tick() {
        this.setState(state => ({
          seconds: state.seconds + 1
        }));
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.interval = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
      }
    
      componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
      }
      
     resetTimer() {
                this.setState(initialState);
        }
    
    render() {
        return <div className="container">
            <div className="timer">
                {this.state.seconds}
            </div>
            <button onClick = {this.resetTimer}>Reset Timer</button>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

and its error is that ... (figure 4)
[figure 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8Pc2.png)

How can I solve the problem of resetting the timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from the "this" scope.

Either you have to bind the function you're using in the class.

```
constructor( props ){
   super( props );
   this.resetTimer = this.resetTimer.bind(this);
}
```

A second option is to use arrow functions when you declare your functions in order to maintain the scope of "this" on the class.

```
resetTimer = () => {
   this.setState(initialState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of writing

```
`resetTimer() {
    this.setState(initialState);
    }`
```

use arrow function

`const resetTimer=()=> {
        this.setState(initialState);
        }`

this will work

Answer (score 0):

**second Solution** - this is because you have not bind the function and calling it in the click event
Please refer [Handling events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

So add this line inside the constructor

```
this.resetTimer = this.resetTimer.bind();
```

I hope this solves your problem :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to bind the method call with the event as suggested by other users If you don't bind the method, It will be always be called with the re-render

First approach

Inside constructor

`this.methodName = this.bind.methodName(this);`

Inside render()

```
render(){
return(
<button onClick={this.methodName}></button>
)
}
```

Second approach

```
render(){
 return(
  <button onClick={()=>this.methodName()}></button>
 )
}
```

Third approach

```
methodName = () => {
//scope
}

render(){
 return(
  <button onClick={this.methodName}></button>
 )
}
```

The third type is not available for older versions of react you have to use class experimental plugin for that, In that case you should always you the first approach

The second approach should always be used when you need to pass a parameter otherwise don't use that

Also please note If you just write

```
<button onClick={this.methodName()}></button>
```

That means you are calling the method, but without binding it with event i.e. whether you click or not the method will always be called

Comment: Thank you from your complete description. I am new in React and it was extremely useful for me. :)